# Change admin password in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using built in Drupal 7 user module, fore user registration, forgot-your-password-emails and all that stuff.

I have forgotten my admin password. I have access to my website which is hosted on 1and1.com and also have access to mysql?

Is it possible to change password or email address through SQL so that I can access the admin page?

If it possible how? Can you somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Generate the query using query generator and run in database http://btobac.com/blog/mysql-query-reset-admin-password-drupal-8-drupal-7-drupal-6-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several research I tried the following code stored it as a php file in the root directory

saved it as password-reset-admin.php

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/password.inc';
if (isset($_GET['pass']) && !empty($_GET['pass'])) { 
$newhash = user_hash_password($_GET['pass']);
}
else {
die('Retry with ?pass=PASSWORD set in the URL');
}
$updatepass = db_update('users') 
->fields(array(
'pass' => $newhash,
// 'name' => 'admin',
// 'mail' => '<a href="mailto:yourmail@domain.com'">yourmail@domain.com'</a>;
))
->condition('uid', '1', '=')
->execute();
print "Done. Please delete this file immediately!";
drupal_exit();
 ?>
```

And after that access the php file through the following:

```
 https://yoursite.com/password-reset-admin.php?pass=newpassword
```

It just worked..:) Hope it helps others.

Please make sure you delete the file.

Comment: This is okay if you want to reset the password on your local instance. And you **have to** delete the `password-reset-admin.php` as soon as it is done. Otherwise can lead to a major loophole. Please note that I've mentioned a simple and secure way to changing the password, using Drush.

Comment: you could always after printing done use unlink to remove file just make sure to keep backup of file also may not want to hint its there and allow users to visit as normal so web site can operate normaly

Comment: I couldn't change password directly in database, using 'newpass' hash from Drupal website. This worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: In Drupal 9 I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal' not found`

Answer (score 6):

If you have [Drush](http://drush.ws) installed, you just have to enter the following command in the terminal from anywhere inside the site root.

```
drush upwd admin --password=mynewpassword
```

Here, `admin` is the user name; who's password will be changed to `mynewpassword`.

Comment: Nice. `drush uli` would also do the trick, though not as quickly

Answer (score 4):

To change the password, you need to have shell access to your website. If not, download a copy of [drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/drupal) on your local machine.

Then, open your terminal and navigate to your Drupal 7 root folder. Then type the following command:

```
./scripts/password-hash.sh NEW_PASSWORD
```

Replace `NEW_PASSWORD` with the new password you need.

This will output a new password hash, copy this password and go to your database manager (phpMyAdmin or similar) and change the admin password to newly generated text.

I don't know of other way to do that, because Drupal is not using `MD5` anymore and use a hashing algorithm instead.

Comment: While this method might work. It is pretty risky to directly change values in the database. Have to very very careful, because one mistake might result in data loss.

Answer (score 3):

Change directory to your Drupal's root.
Then generate the new hash.

In case of **Drupal 7**:

```
$ php scripts/password-hash.sh 'your-new-pass-here'
```

Then execute SQL query to update the administrator's password:

```
UPDATE users_field_data SET pass='$S$Do7UQjqtEELNccdi92eCXcVJ2KnwUeHrSbK3YhFm8oR3lRJQbMB2' WHERE uid = 1;
```

In case of **Drupal 8** path to script will be:

```
$ php core/scripts/password-hash.sh 'your-new-pass-here'
```

Update DB:

```
UPDATE users_field_data SET pass='$S$Do7UQjqtEELNccdi92eCXcVJ2KnwUeHrSbK3YhFm8oR3lRJQbMB2' WHERE uid = 1;
```

Clean the cache:

```
DELETE FROM cache_entity WHERE cid = 'values:user:1';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to database, then...

- Go to the users table in your database and change the admin's email to an email that you have access to.
- Afterward, head over to yoursite.com/user/password and enter the email that just changed.
- Go to your email and click on the reset link to go into your site and reset your password.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Tested and it works!

With the access to the table "users"  in your Database via PhpMyAdmin for example (i.e. this table can have a prefix that you have already mentionned during the Drupal installation part, so yourPrefix_ can be your project's name as mywebsitename_, and in this case you'll have mywebsitename_users).

You should alter the "pass" column associated with the "uid" column with the value 1 (i.e 1 for the admin user account).

As the encrypted value for the password: Admin_12345 is =>

$S$DifCVXg9tNtHadziyyQJQVLAaZzW5EgS6OjR56D.mk8MpNQs1II2

You can accede to your admin account after replacing the old hashed password value stored in your database that you have totally forgotten.

Don't forget to change the password: Admin_12345 after you accede to your account with an other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate query [here](http://btobac.com/blog/mysql-query-reset-admin-password-drupal-8-drupal-7-drupal-6-phpmyadmin) and run the query in database.

Comment: No you can't, the website is down.

Comment: http://btobac.com/blog/mysql-query-reset-admin-password-drupal-8-drupal-7-drupal-6-phpmyadmin